# Windows Phone 8.1 xbox music

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, xbox-music

Is it any way to control **Xbox Music** on **Windows Phone 8.1** or **Windows Phone 8.0** from another application. I want to create an application with different style controls which start local music in background, getting some information from **xbox music** and so on. Is native Windows Phone 8.1 **xbox music** provide any API? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with the [official API](http://music.xbox.com/Developer)?

Getting started with the API [is on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546659.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

the Xbox Music API I could not find it working for windows Phone 8.1 but there are packages for Windows Phone 8 and windows 8.1